# ¿Cómo verificar que se hace petición HTTP desde un dispositivo móvil?

Tags: json, google-play

Buen día, soy nuevo por aquí, ojalá alguien pueda ayudarme.

Tengo una aplicación móvil que hace una petición HTTP a mi servidor web.
La petición devuelve una lista de videos y sus urls para reproducirlos dentro de la aplicación móvil, mi pregunta es, ¿existe alguna forma de comprobar que la petición se hace desde un dispositivo móvil?, se me ocurría que talvéz podría ser comprobando la cuenta de Google Play generando un token en la aplicación que luego se comprueba desde el servidor web.

¿Alguien sabe como hacer esto?

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Añade un parametro codificado en la petición http que solo esté en móvil, así sabrás que solo viene de la app

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu tiempo y tu respuesta, sabes como puedo crear un parámetro codificado que solo esté en móvil desde una aplicación creada en Cordova?

Comment: Porque no creas un Log así cuando hagas la petición con tan solo debugar el dispositivo podrás ver la petición que estas mandando al servidor.